# Shower Leak - Panels + Glass Door + tray

Tags: water, shower, leak

First time poster here and likely about to become a new DIYer (and probably day drinker after this). I am at the end of my rope and have seen really great posts here, so I hope I can get some kind of direction with this.

Pictures of the current shower [here](https://imgur.com/a/wchiqYH)

My home has a tiny little shower (34x34) in my master bathroom that's situated behind the door. We moved in and it had a half wall on one side, with a glass frame and door, with cultured marble and a bottom tray. It was perpetually leaking in the front of corner of the wall, so we hired a couple handymen that had done some good work on my neighbors house to rip it out. They took everything out, found that the builders had installed the cultured marble onto actual drywall and had the drywall resting in the lip of the shower. No mold or subfloor damage when they ripped everything out (I saw the space when they removed everything).

They installed a new shower valve, put in a new tray, put in panels with a black plastic wall between the studs and the shower panels. The panels were installed and rest in the tray with no caulking on the edges (at first), and all seemed well. A few weeks later, I looked at the wall, and found that the leaking started all over again in the same corner.

I've had them come out several times to try and find it, but it seems like the shower door frame leaks into that corner no matter what.

They even removed the door and put silicone behind the frame to prevent it from coming out of this tiny corner where the tray lip and wall panel ends.

I've had a plumber come in and check the shower valve and plumbing from the other side of the wall (bedroom side), and he didn't see any issues with plumbing. After the new shower started leaking the first time, they came out and put silicone along the bottom edge of the panels. I've seen here that those should not be sealed, but it was leaking already so it was a troubleshooting step.

It is such a small amount of water that it thankfully has not caused extensive damage, just emotional trauma.
I am considering removing the door again to fully remove the silicone under it, but I fear that I'm going to need to rip all of this out and reinstall it myself. I've already started removing the silicone from the inside edges and tested with a bit more water: more leaking :(.
Any thoughts or recommendations based on my pictures? I've circled the spot where the trim outside, the wall panel, and the tray lip all meet. Water starts beading in that spot when pouring water in the corner inside the shower, but it also seems to happen when it's running.

My current plan is:

1. I'm going to remove the door, clear out silicone, pour water around
   edges to see if there's a leak.
2. Cry
3. remove the wall panels
4. cry some more
5. come back here to see what to do next

Comment: Just wondering if it is door opening/closing that is causing enough movement to open up the sealant.

Comment: Is there caulk between the whole frame and the surround? Not just at the wall or just at the bottom? Have you backed out the screws and put a dab of clear silicone under the heads?

Comment: The bottom edge of the panels shouldn't be caulked? Why not? Based on the installation instructions linked from https://www.homedepot.com/p/DreamLine-SlimLine-36-in-x-36-in-Single-Threshold-Shower-Base-in-White-Center-Drain-Base-with-Back-Walls-DL-6194C-01/204401568, page 40 of https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/b4/b46db506-0c2e-4d4c-8c90-382e04e0e0ec.pdf calls for caulk at the base.

Comment: @popham

Hmmm, Ok, you're right. I only recently removed the caulking (today), but it's been leaking with the caulking/silicone at the bottom.

Comment: @popham
It seems to be the corner where the glass panel frame meets the wall, but obviously that's hard to tell. As I was removing the caulking on the bottom, the outside surface was white, but there was mildew on the inside that was between the panel and the base, so I assume water's been sneaking in somewhere, and settles around the base, finding it's way out on those front corners.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I started removing the caulking around the bottom of the shower door frame, water was coming out of it (small amounts). I have not used this shower in 2+ weeks